# JavaScript scopes on local and global variable

Tags: javascript

Here is the Code:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    alert(foo)
    if (!foo) {
        var foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

While foo is the Global variable. After calling the b() function, foo is alerting as the undefined. As it is global variable it should alert as 1 Right? If i am wrong please correct me.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v2rbdmt/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two variables called `foo`.

One declared on line 1, which is global and another declared on line 5, which is local to the `bar` function.

Remember that `var` statements are hoisted, so if you have a local variable for a function, it is local for *all* of the function.

When you alert the value for `foo` on lines 3 and 7, you are alerting the local `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.. Before declaring the second variable on line 5.... i am alerting the global variable... then it shows undefined

Comment: @answer99 — No, you aren't. Read my answer again. Pay special attention to the last two paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

No... since you are declaring `foo` inside the `bar` function as a local variable the global instance will not be accessed while using `foo` inside the function.

You are getting `undefined` because of variable hoisting, where all variable declaration will be moved to the top of the function so at execution your function will look like

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    var foo;
    alert(foo)
    if (!foo) {
        foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```